# sorting messages with tag in django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm receiving a list of messages, each message has a tag. It may be "info", "warning", "danger" and "spreadsheet". I need to display the first three first and then spreadsheet's but in collapsible if there are more than 3 of them.

So for all messages BUT spreadsheet the template is:

```
    <div class="row banner">
        <ul class="banner-message">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="banner-message--{{ message.tags }}" {% else %} class="banner-message--info" {% endif %}>
                    <div class="message-content">
                        <p>{{ message|safe }}</p>
                        <span class="close">&times;</span></div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

For tags with "spreadsheet" tag the template is:

```
    <div class="row banner">
        <ul class="banner-message">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li class="{% if forloop.counter >= 3 %}collapsible_content{% endif %} banner-message--info">
                    <div class='message-content'>
                        <p>{{ message|safe }}</p>
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if messages|length > 3 %}
                <button id="show_more" class="btn btn-secondary collapsible_button">Show all</button>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Where button is shown for spreadsheet messages if there are more then 3 of them and shows all of them on click.

Problem is that I receive these messages in one array and I have no guarantee that they won't be all mixed up in different order.

I need to sort them somehow with `message.tags` to two separate arrays? Or use some smart if but I cannot figure out how to achieve that in the template. Could you please help?

EDIT:
After comment below I am trying to sort the messages in the view.py

```
m = messages.get_messages(request)
        if len(m) > 0:
            context['msgs'] = m.filter(tags__in=['info', 'warning', 'danger']).order_by('tags')
            context['spreadsheet'] = m.filter(tags='spreadsheet')
```

m is `FallbackStorage` object and it doesn't have `filter` method. `m.objects` and `FallbackStorage.objects` do not work either (for the same reason: has no attribute 'objects'). I've tried to do all above with `messages` straight away (without the `get_messages` method) but the result is the same. How to filter this correctly?

Comment: Try to sort and group the messages in your view, and just use your template for formatting.

Comment: @evergreen Thanks. I'm trying. Could you help? I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_messages` is a utility function and not a class method. You can read more about how to use it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages).

In your view you can do:

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
...
message_list = get_messages(request)
messages = []
spreadsheet_messages = []
for message in message_list:
    tags = message.tags
    if ("info" in tags) or ("warning" in tags) or ("danger" in tags):
        messages.append(message)
    if "spreadsheet" in tags:
        spreadsheet_messages.append(message)
context["messages"] = messages
context["spreadsheet"] = spreadsheet_messages
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can divide messages in two different querysets. On your views.py:

```
context['messages'] = messages.filter(tags__in = ['info','warning','danger']).order_by('tags')
context['spreadsheet'] = messages.filter(tags = 'spreadsheet')
```

On your template:

```
<div class="row banner">
    <ul class="banner-message">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="banner-message--{{ message.tags }}" {% else %} class="banner-message--info" {% endif %}>
                <div class="message-content">
                    <p>{{ message|safe }}</p>
                    <span class="close">&times;</span></div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row banner">
    <ul class="banner-message">
        {% for message in spreadsheet %}
            <li class="{% if forloop.counter >= 3 %}collapsible_content{% endif %} banner-message--info">
                <div class='message-content'>
                    <p>{{ message|safe }}</p>
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if messages|length > 3 %}
            <button id="show_more" class="btn btn-secondary collapsible_button">Show all</button>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

According to you comment. I suggest to try something like this:

```
msgs = []
spreadsheet = []
m = messages.get_messages(request)
    if len(m) > 0:
        for mensaje in m:
            #TRY THE THREE OPTIONS BECAUSE I DON'T KNOW THE MESSAGES' STRUCTURE#
            if 'spreadsheet' in message['tags']:
            #if 'spreadsheet' in message.tags:
            #if 'spreadshhet' in message.tags():
               spreadsheet.append(mensaje)
            else:
               msgs.append(mensaje)
        context['msgs'] = msgs
        context['spreadsheet'] = spreadsheet
```

Comment: `messages` do not have `filter` method. I'm trying to retrieve them first with `get_messages(request)` but doesn't really work either.